# Comparing multiple strings and order answers

Tags: java, compareto

I am trying to compare 3 difference words and then order them, however I am not getting the right answer. Some direction would be a great help!
Very very new to Java and have been stuck on this problem for too long.

So far I am using this:

```
`// word1, word2, and word3 
   /* If word1 is greater than word2, 
    * and word2 IS greater than word3 and word3 is NOT greater then word1: display word1,     word2, word3 
    */
   result1  =   word1.compareTo(word2);
   result1a =   word1.compareTo(word3);
   result1b =   word2.compareTo(word3);

//display and compare information
       if (result1 > result1a + result1b)  
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, word1 + word2 + word3);

       else if (result1 < result1a + result1b)
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, word2 + word3 + word1);
```

`

Comment: compare in the sense what? length?

Comment: Are you talking about `string's length` OR talking about `lexicographical precedence` when you mean wordx is greater than wordy?

Comment: Sorry, I want the message to show the words in ascending order.

Comment: Yes, lexicograhical precedence

Comment: Trying to figure out how to post my code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String message;
if(word2.compareTo(word1) < 0) { //word2 < word1
    if(word3.compareTo(word1) < 0) { //word3 < word1
        if(word3.compareTo(word2) < 0) { //word3 < word2
            message = word3 + word2 + word1;
        } else { //word2 <= word3
            message = word2 + word3 + word1;
        }
    } else { //word1 <= word3
        message = word2 + word1 + word3;
    }
} else { //word1 <= word2
    if(word3.compareTo(word2) < 0) { //word3 < word2
        if(word3.compareTo(word1) < 0) { //word3 < word1
            message = word3 + word1 + word2;
        } else { //word1 <= word3
            message = word1 + word3 + word2;
        }
    } else { //word2 <= word3
        message = word1 + word2 + word3;
    }
}
```

This is using the lexicographic/alphabetical order. If you want to compare the words using their lengths, you have to replace each `s1.compareTo(s2)` by `s1.length() - s2.length()` (you should have a positive integer if s1 is bigger than s2).

Comment: Worked a treat. Thank you. Clearly I was way off the mark, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); //create an arraylist

list.add("ccc")  //add the strings
list.add("aaa");
list.add("bbb");

Collections.sort(list); //this will sort the list in lexographical precedence

//now get the words and process as you want
```

Comment: Actually,he is trying to do it using `compareTo()` method! So,I guess your answer won't help him much!